# Bijection between complex valued functions on the unit circle and on the real line

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Let $\mathbb{T}$ be the unit circle in the complex plane, that is $\mathbb{T}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z| = 1\}$. I have read that there is a bijection between the class of complex-valued functions on $\mathbb{T}$ and the class of complex-valued $2\pi$-periodic functions on the real line $\mathbb{R}$. This bijection was explained like the following

> A function $f$ on the unit circle induces a 2$\pi$-periodic function $g$ on the real line by
> $$ g(x) = f(e^{ix}), \;\;\; x\in\mathbb{R}. $$
> This correspondence is clearly bijective.

I have tried to prove the result above myself but I am unfamiliar with the notion of a bijection between classes. If we are talking about the *sets* of functions on $\mathbb{T}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ then I understand. Is he just using sloppy wording? Does he mean to say that $f(e^{ix})$ is the bijection from the set of 2$\pi$-periodic, complex-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ to the set of functions on $\mathbb{T}$? If so, I need some help in showing that because I have not come up with anything myself.

Comment: It is common to use the terms "class" and "set" interchangeably outside set theory. The bijection maps a given $f$ to the function $g$ defined by the equation. You have to show that this is a bijection between the set of all functions on the unit circle and the set of all $2\pi$-periodic functions on the real line.

Comment: @RobArthan Alright, that clears that up. I'm still not sure how to show it. I can see that f(e$^{ix})$ is 2$\pi$-periodic and is on the real line. I try to start off by supposing that 

$$g(x) = f_1(e^{ix}) = f_2(e^{ix}) $$
and I want to see if this leads to $f_1(e^{ix}) = f_2(e^{ix})$ somehow, but I don't see a way to move forward. 

Alternatively, I thought I maybe could show that f(e$^{ix}$) has an inverse, but I am not sure how to do that either. I'm thinking maybe g(xe$^{-ix}$) is an inverse since it gives back f(x).